# Coredata in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

Hello I am having an issue with core data in Swift, this doesn't show an error but also doesn't print anything when I believe it should be returning 'Joe' + 'pass' in console. Could anyone help please?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    newUser.setValue("Joe", forKey: "username")

    newUser.setValue("pass", forKey: "password")

    do {
     try context.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("Couldn't save user data")
        print(error)
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        var results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        results = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        if results.count > 0 {
        for results in results {
            print(results)
            }}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: "for results in results" - is this really your code? Because that shouldn't compile. In the meantime, break on the line above the for and examine `results` in the debugger, does it contain anything?

Comment: I was shown this from a post here yesterday under the same issue when I didn't get my error fixed, I'm really new to Swift so just trying to find my feet. Take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592609/core-data-issue-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realised what my issue was, I hadn't actually renamed by Entity to 'Users' I'd kept it as 'Entity' so when I was doing

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject 
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
```

I should have actually have replaced both Users with 'Entity' which now fixes my issue, thanks I guess for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create your own coredata class (as a subclass of NSManagedObject) and then create the array out of that class.
2. specify exactly what you want to print. In your case

   newUser.username

Comment: How do I go about doing this, sorry I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: Go to where you created your coredata class, chose the class you want and go under editor -> create nsmanagedobject subclass. This should create a class for you that you can use directly

Comment: err, I don't believe I have a core data class, unless you're referring to 'Core_Data_Demo.xcdatamodeld'? and when I go file > new file > class > it doesn't show me that option?